# SQL Server 2008 stopped receiving network connections after SP2 installed

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-7

After SP2 I was unable to connect to SQL Server 2008. I found that the SQL Server Browser service was stopped. I enabled Browser, but it did not help. Everything was fine before SP2. My OS is Windows 7 64-bit.

Protocols for SQL Server: Enabled Shared memory, Named pipes and TCP/IP

Under TCP/IP, all settings seem OK.

A connection fails from the local network to this computer, but otherwise the server is working OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Windows firewall exception was removed after SQL Server 2008 SP2. All working was fine after I added the exception.

Comment: Please mark this as the correct answer (there's a white checkmark to the left of this Answer, click it and it will turn green).

Comment: I know how to make question answered ;) I have experience at Stackoverflow and other, but as I am new here and can't vote up to thank the contributor, i gave him a chance to update answer so that he gets some points for helping ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Browser service doesn't enable connectivity; it assists in locating and connecting to SQL Server instances. I would check to see which protocols are enabled in SQL Server Configuration Manager.

*[SQL Server Browser Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087.aspx)*

Comment: I would give you a vote up but i have not enough reputation here, sorry. You can update answer with firewall and i will make it green because you helped in solving this.